# Lombok + Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse-kepler, lombok

So, after updating eclipse from Helios to Kepler, I found my Lombok-dependent project to be full of errors, due to eclipse not seeing the added methods by @Getter and stuff, so i reinstalled Lombok, however eclipse either crashed or just didnt see the methods, depending on how i run it. If I ran it from eclipse.exe from windows explorer, it starts without lombok, and if i type it into the run dialog it just crashes like this:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
   C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx512m
   -javaagent:lombok.jar
   -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -jar C:\Program Files\eclipse \\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
   -os win32
   -ws win32
   -arch x86_64
   -showsplash C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000\splash.bmp
   -launcher C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe
   -name Eclipse
   --launcher.library C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835\eclipse_1503.dll
   -startup C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
   --launcher.appendVmargs
   -exitdata 198c_5c
   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
   -vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx512m
   -javaagent:lombok.jar
   -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -jar C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

Comment: Do you use gradle or maven?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen the same problem after installing lombok with Eclipse Kepler. To start Eclipse I defined a symbolic link which points to the Eclipse installation deirectory and which passes a `-data` option to `eclipse.exe`.

The problem was that the references to `lombok.jar` in the `eclipse.ini` file were relative. I have changed these references to absolute references and since then lombok works.

In the file `eclipse.ini` I replaced the lines

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

with

```
-javaagent:D:\eclipse\kepler\lombok.jar
-Xbootclasspath/a:D:\eclipse\kepler\lombok.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. I start Eclipse from the command line. Providing absolute paths worked.

Comment: Since I have installed Lombok Eclipse became horribly slow. This solved the problem.